# Javascript - Unnamed Button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a listener for a button that does not have an ID. How would I create a listener for the following element:

```
<button class="jss459 jss433 jss444 jss445 jss447 jss448 jss321" tabindex="0" type="button" title="Press Enter"><span class="jss434">Quick Search</span><span class="jss471"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const myelement = document.querySelector('.jss459.jss433.jss444.jss445.jss447.jss448.jss321');
```

or

```
const myelement = document.querySelector('[title="Press Enter"]');
```

But you'd probably be better off with a more unique selector :)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()`

It allows You to grab the element by the class name

```
const button = document.querySelector(<classHere>);
button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    //code here 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to return the first element that matches the selector, for example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log('The button was clicked');
});
```

```html
<button class="jss459 jss433 jss444 jss445 jss447 jss448 jss321" tabindex="0" type="button" title="Press Enter"><span class="jss434"> Quick Search</span><span class="jss471"></span> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you **ONLY** want to select a button that doesn't have an ID attribute. In that case, you can use querySelectorAll to select all the buttons on the page and then add an Event Listener the buttons that don't have the ID attribute. Below would be the code for that:

```
let allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

allButtons.forEach( button => {
    if (!button.hasAttribute('id')) {
         button.addEventListener('click', buttonWithoutId)
    }
})

function buttonWithoutId() {
     alert('this button does not have an ID!')
}
```

Comment: const test = document.querySelector('button:not([id])'); would be more efficient.

Comment: I think you meant document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id])'); -- but yes that works. I'd also check for id's without attributes or empty id attributes while I'm at it